# How to check when firebase user was created?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Im using a schedule function to delete unverified users. The schedule function runs every 24 hours. Now the Problem that I have is : Lets say a user created his account 3 minutes ago and did not verify his email address yet. And then the functions runs and delete his/her/it Account. What I want is to give the user lets say 5 hours to verify his account . So my question is how can I check that in my function ?
Here's my function

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import admin from "firebase-admin";

export default  functions.pubsub.schedule('every 24 hours').onRun(async(context) => {
    console.log('This will be run every 24 hours!');
    const users = []
    const listAllUsers = (nextPageToken) => {
        // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
        return admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken).then((listUsersResult) => {
            listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
                users.push(userRecord)
            });
            if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
                // List next batch of users.
                listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            const functions = require("firebase-functions");

            functions.logger.error("Hello from info. Here's an problem:", error);
        });
    };
    // Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
    await listAllUsers();
    const unVerifiedUsers = users.filter((user) => !user.emailVerified).map((user) => user.uid)

    //DELETING USERS
    return admin.auth().deleteUsers(unVerifiedUsers).then((deleteUsersResult) => {
        console.log(`Successfully deleted ${deleteUsersResult.successCount} users`);
        console.log(`Failed to delete ${deleteUsersResult.failureCount} users`);
        deleteUsersResult.errors.forEach((err) => {
            console.log(err.error.toJSON());
        });
        return true
    }).catch((error) => {
        const functions = require("firebase-functions");

    functions.logger.error("Hello from info. Here's an problem:", error);
        return false
    });
});
```

If any question please let me know !

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with the Firebase Auth APIs.  You will have to record the time on your own in a separate database, and using that database to find out the time you need to know.

Comment: ok thank you . But can you give me  an example how i can then check it in the function. Lets say i save the recordedtimes in FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(recorder).doc(uid).set({date:Datetime.now());

Comment: Asking for example code is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  If you want help here, you must make an attempt on your own, and if that doesn't work, post what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```js
import { auth } from 'firebase-admin'

// ...your function

let uid = request.auth?.uid
let userCreation = await auth()
    .getUser(uid)
    .then((user) => {
        return user.metadata.creationTime
    })
```